# how to prevent sudo from executing a non root file?

Tags: permissions, sudo, security

I want to prevent `sudo` from executing files not owned by root.

so, to allow sudo run such file, I want the file to be:
`chown root:root filename`
`chmod go-w filename`

Is it possible to limit `sudo` this way?

It should also be inherited by graphical `sudo` like runners (gksudo, kdesudo, ...), but I think it could be too much tricky, not sure tho.

Comment: I don't think that's possible on a system-wide basis. If the file in question is a shell script, then you can check the uid of the user running the file and if it's 0, then quit there.

Comment: I'd say it is impossible, since pretty much any shell on the system is owned by root, as is `chown` itself, and editors like `vim` and `emacs` which can spawn commands, as well as commands like perl, awk and python, and so on...

Comment: @muru so you mean that even if I manage to allow only a root:root go-w file to be executed, it could still child a non secure script? :(

Comment: @AquariusPower yep. The only way is careful whitelisting.

Answer (score 1):

It's a genuinely interesting idea but not without issues.

You could add a "semiadmin" group (your choice on the name), put a user in that group instead of the "sudo" group, and then add `/etc/sudoers` lines using wildcards to match the common places root-owned commands live:

```
%semiadmin (ALL)=/usr/bin/*,/bin/*,/sbin/*
```

The problem with this approach is you would also need to prevent somebody using any editor (or `visudo`), or let them edit their user... If they can do that, they can elevate their privileges.

Simply put, it's much easier to specify exactly which commands you want them to use.
A list of commands you've sanitised for loopholes.

Comment: I see, so I also have to remove all users from group sudo (that are on it of course) right? very interesting, seems a good shield indeed; to reinforce it I found this: http://superuser.com/a/735286/157532; the sanitized list seems the best way in a sense that: keep admin stuff to admin to do. A few commands with limited parameters may be made available then, thx!

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want people to have unlimited rights, kick them out of the sudo group.

Answer (score -1):

Login as the owner of the file who is not root and revoke execution permission from other users using this command

```
chmod o-x filename
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's complete nonsense. -1